# How To Have One IP With Multiple Servers

Tags: webserver, apache-virtualhost

I have a website, let's just call it example.com. Right now, I've got the URL http://www.example.com, which has the DNS address of 10.0.1.1(:80) which is port forwarded to 192.168.0.14 on my network.

I also want to have a website at http://edu.example.com which would be hosted on my other server, but I only have one router therefore, only one IP address.

I have tried using a VirtualHost in my apache config file, but it can't specify a directory on another device

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up a proxy directive for Apache to do this. Look at the ProxyPass directive on Apache's [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) page for specifics.

Answer (score 2):

I would definetly do this with a Nginx reverse proxy.

You can have nginx on the same machine as your apache server and you can configure it to redirect requests to the secondary server based on the url.

In this example, apache has been (previously) configured to serve example.com on port 8080, while edu.example.com is served on x.x.x.100:80

```
server { 
server_name example.com;

  # app1 reverse proxy follow
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

}

server { 
  server_name edu.example.com;

  # app2 reverse proxy settings follow
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_pass http://x.x.x.100:80;
}
```

You will probably need to expand the example with definitions for access and error logs.

Another great advantage that this setup offers is SSL/TLS offloading: you can have the apache backends serve plain http and nginx to serve SSL/TLS enabled https, so you have your certificates in one single server, which makes it much easier and tidier to maintain.